# Google search result has wrong description

Tags: meta-tags, google-search, meta

my page has set description in meta like this

```
<meta name="description" content="My best website"/>
```

Until now this description was displayed with my page in google search result. Now there is totally different text from footer in my page.

Can I change it somehow to be like before?

Comment: resubmit your page (via sitemap etc) to google webmaster. Also check that content of your description tag appears on your page, Google may perhaps think that your description tag is irrelivent to your actual page content text and therefore will ignore it and just take stuff from the page itself.

Comment: @Martin - Submit this as an answer so petros can accept it and other users can vote on it. Don't answer in comments; it makes the question appear unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

resubmit your page (via sitemap etc) to google webmaster. Also check that content of your description tag appears on your page, Google may perhaps think that your description tag is irrelivent to your actual page content text and therefore will ignore it and just take stuff from the page itself.

Comment: Description tag on my page is ok. How can I resubmit page in google webmaster?

Comment: run/generate a new sitemap and then resubmit the new sitemap to google webmaster tools